# How to put Windows login process on hold

Tags: authentication

I am trying to create an application/service which will be running in the machine without any console or remote log-in. And if any user is trying to log-in this application will perform following task in sequence:

1. Put the log-in process on hold.
2. Do its own processing and and upon completion of its work,
3. It should allow the Windows to resume with the log-in process.

I could not find any way to put the windows log-in process on hold. Any suggestion/help appreciated.

**Note:** I am using Windows Embedded Standard 7.